# Fetch: POST JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I'm trying to POST a JSON object using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch).

From what I can understand, I need to attach a stringified object to the body of the request, e.g.:

```js
fetch("/echo/json/",
{
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 2})
})
.then(function(res){ console.log(res) })
.catch(function(res){ console.log(res) })
```

When using [jsfiddle's JSON echo](https://jsfiddle.net/abbpbah4/) I'd expect to see the object I've sent (`{a: 1, b: 2}`) back, but this does not happen - chrome devtools doesn't even show the JSON as part of the request, which means that it's not being sent.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski chrome 42, which is meant to have [full fetch support](http://caniuse.com/#search=fetch)

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/abbpbah4/2/  what data you're expecting ? because get request of https://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/json is showing empty object. `{}`

Comment: @KaushikKishore edited to clarify expected output. `res.json()` should return `{a: 1, b: 2}`.

Comment: @Razor I called this `https://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/json` with post data `{"a":1,"b":2}` `content-type: application/json` from rest client and I'm getting `{}` object
That indicated that there is no problem in `fetch` . I think so

Comment: @Razor https://jsfiddle.net/abbpbah4/3/ in this fiddle I added a debugger. when debugger will hit check the value of `res` this time your promise object is not there. so this `fetch` would have success method. that might work. ;)

Comment: You forgot to include the `json` property that contains the data you want to send. However, I the `body` is not being treated correctly anyway. See this fiddle to see that the delay of 5 seconds gets skipped.  http://jsfiddle.net/99arsnkg/ Also, when you try to add additional headers, they are ignored. This is probably an issue with `fetch()` itself.

Comment: Bottom line its a pig to use. There should be an overriding Text() property that always works irrelevant of the (bloody) header types.

Answer (score 1211, accepted):

With ES2017 [`async/await` support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions), this is how to `POST` a JSON payload:

```js
(async () => {
  const rawResponse = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 'Textual content'})
  });
  const content = await rawResponse.json();

  console.log(content);
})();
```

Can't use ES2017? See @vp_art's [answer using promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42493030/304174)

The question however is asking for an issue caused by **a long since fixed chrome bug.**
Original answer follows.

> chrome devtools doesn't even show the JSON as part of the request

**This is the real issue here**, and it's a [bug with chrome devtools](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=457484), fixed in Chrome 46.

That code works fine - it is POSTing the JSON correctly, it just cannot be seen.

> I'd expect to see the object I've sent back

that's not working because that is not the [correct format for JSfiddle's echo](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html#json).

The [correct code](https://jsfiddle.net/Razor/abbpbah4/5/) is:

```js
var payload = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};

var data = new FormData();
data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( payload ) );

fetch("/echo/json/",
{
    method: "POST",
    body: data
})
.then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
.then(function(data){ alert( JSON.stringify( data ) ) })
```

For endpoints accepting JSON payloads, **the original code is correct**

Comment: To be on the safe side, it would be good to confirm `res.ok` in case the response code is some kind of error. It'd also be good to have a `.catch()` clause at the end.

I realize this is just a sample snippet, but bear these things in mind for real world usage.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being redundant but I'd like to point out that it does work successfully with `PUT` requests as well.

Comment: I did not need `'Accept': 'application/json'` nor `content-type` when sending json data.

Comment: @Timo: this depends very much on your server; the server is not *required* to use these fields. But the server might emit different data depending on `Accept`, and it might require `content-type` to accept json. Better set both to avoid endless debugging when the server software updates.

Comment: Love that it is also wrapped by self invoking asynchronous function.

Answer (score 355):

I think your issue is `jsfiddle` can process `form-urlencoded` request only.  But correct way to make json request is pass correct `json` as a body:

```js
fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({a: 7, str: 'Some string: &=&'})
}).then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: For those who aren't familiar with arrow functions, you have to **return** `res.json()` there, to get the data in the next `.then()` call.

Comment: You don't have to use return if you don't use curly braces.

Answer (score 113):

From search engines, I ended up on this topic for non-json posting data with fetch, so thought I would add this.

For *non-json* you don't have to use form data. You can simply set the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and use a string:

```
fetch('url here', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, // this line is important, if this content-type is not set it wont work
    body: 'foo=bar&blah=1'
});
```

An alternative way to build that `body` string, rather then typing it out as I did above, is to use libraries. For instance the `stringify` function from [`query-string`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) or [`qs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) packages. So using this it would look like:

```
import queryString from 'query-string'; // import the queryString class

fetch('url here', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, // this line is important, if this content-type is not set it wont work
    body: queryString.stringify({for:'bar', blah:1}) //use the stringify object of the queryString class
});
```

Answer (score 56):

After spending some times, reverse engineering jsFiddle, trying to generate payload - there is an effect.

Please take eye (care) on line `return response.json();` where response is not a response - it is promise.

```
var json = {
    json: JSON.stringify({
        a: 1,
        b: 2
    }),
    delay: 3
};

fetch('/echo/json/', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: 'json=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(json.json)) + '&delay=' + json.delay
})
.then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(function (result) {
    alert(result);
})
.catch (function (error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error);
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/egxt6cpz/46/ && Firefox > 39 && Chrome > 42

Comment: yw. Curious detail, it works for me in the old way with `fetch` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984893/fetch-post-fails-on-post-json-body-with-sails-js?noredirect=1#comment71171442_41984893) instead the `application/json`. Perhaps you know why ...

Comment: The `Content-Type` is `application/json`, but your actual `body` appears to be `x-www-form-urlencoded` - I don't think this should work? If it does work, your server must be pretty forgiving. The answer by @vp_arth below appears to be the correct one.

Comment: 30 minutes wasted trying to convert to json an awaited response

Answer (score 42):

2021 answer: just in case you land here looking for how to make GET and POST Fetch api requests using async/await or promises as compared to axios.

I'm using jsonplaceholder fake API to demonstrate:

Fetch api GET request using async/await:

```
         const asyncGetCall = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
                 const data = await response.json();
                // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
                 console.log(data);
               } catch(error) {
            // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
                  console.log(error)
                 } 
            }


          asyncGetCall()
```

Fetch api POST request using async/await:

```
    const asyncPostCall = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
                 method: 'POST',
                 headers: {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                   },
                   body: JSON.stringify({
             // your expected POST request payload goes here
                     title: "My post title",
                     body: "My post content."
                    })
                 });
                 const data = await response.json();
              // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
                 console.log(data);
               } catch(error) {
             // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)

                  console.log(error)
                 } 
            }

asyncPostCall()
```

GET request using Promises:

```
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
   // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
   console.log(error)
  })
```

POST request using Promises:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
   body: JSON.stringify({
     // your expected POST request payload goes here
      title: "My post title",
      body: "My post content."
      })
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
   // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
  // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
   console.log(error)
  })
```

GET request using Axios:

```
        const axiosGetCall = async () => {
            try {
              const { data } = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
              console.log(`data: `, data)
           
            } catch (error) {
    // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
              console.log(`error: `, error)
            }
          }
    
    axiosGetCall()
```

POST request using Axios:

```
const axiosPostCall = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',  {
      // your expected POST request payload goes here
      title: "My post title",
      body: "My post content."
      })
   // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
      console.log(`data: `, data)
   
    } catch (error) {
  // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
      console.log(`error: `, error)
    }
  }


axiosPostCall()
```

Answer (score 22):

Had the same issue - no `body` was sent from a client to a server.
Adding `Content-Type` header solved it for me:

```
var headers = new Headers();

headers.append('Accept', 'application/json'); // This one is enough for GET requests
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); // This one sends body

return fetch('/some/endpoint', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'same-origin',
    credentials: 'include',
    redirect: 'follow',
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({
        name: 'John',
        surname: 'Doe'
    }),
}).then(resp => {
    ...
}).catch(err => {
   ...
})
```

Answer (score 20):

I have created a thin wrapper around fetch() with many improvements if you are using a purely json REST API:

```js
// Small library to improve on fetch() usage
const api = function(method, url, data, headers = {}){
  return fetch(url, {
    method: method.toUpperCase(),
    body: JSON.stringify(data),  // send it as stringified json
    credentials: api.credentials,  // to keep the session on the request
    headers: Object.assign({}, api.headers, headers)  // extend the headers
  }).then(res => res.ok ? res.json() : Promise.reject(res));
};

// Defaults that can be globally overwritten
api.credentials = 'include';
api.headers = {
  'csrf-token': window.csrf || '',    // only if globally set, otherwise ignored
  'Accept': 'application/json',       // receive json
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'  // send json
};

// Convenient methods
['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'].forEach(method => {
  api[method] = api.bind(null, method);
});
```

To use it you have the variable `api` and 4 methods:

```js
api.get('/todo').then(all => { /* ... */ });
```

And within an `async` function:

```js
const all = await api.get('/todo');
// ...
```

Example with jQuery:

```js
$('.like').on('click', async e => {
  const id = 123;  // Get it however it is better suited

  await api.put(`/like/${id}`, { like: true });

  // Whatever:
  $(e.target).addClass('active dislike').removeClass('like');
});
```

Answer (score 13):

This is related to `Content-Type`. As you might have noticed from other discussions and answers to this question some people were able to solve it by setting `Content-Type: 'application/json'`. Unfortunately in my case it didn't work, my POST request was still empty on the server side.

However, if you try with jQuery's `$.post()` and it's working, the reason is probably because of jQuery using `Content-Type: 'x-www-form-urlencoded'` instead of `application/json`.

```
data = Object.keys(data).map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key])).join('&')
fetch('/api/', {
    method: 'post', 
    credentials: "include", 
    body: data, 
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
```

Answer (score 9):

The top answer doesn't work for PHP7, because it has wrong encoding, but I could figure the right encoding out with the other answers. This code also sends authentication cookies, which you probably want when dealing with e.g. PHP forums:

```
julia = function(juliacode) {
    fetch('julia.php', {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "include", // send cookies
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            //'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" // otherwise $_POST is empty
        },
        body: "juliacode=" + encodeURIComponent(juliacode)
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.json(); // .text();
    })
    .then(function(myJson) {
        console.log(myJson);
    });
}
```

Comment: For PHP you can also use
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
to get the array from
fetch(requestURI, {method:'POST', body: JSON.stringify(object)});

Answer (score 7):

```
**//POST a request**


const createTodo = async (todo) =>  {
    let options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type":"application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(todo)      
    }
    let p = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", options);
    let response = await p.json();
    return response;
}

**//GET request**

const getTodo = async (id) => {
    let response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id);
  let r = await response.json();
  return r;
}
const mainFunc = async () => {
    let todo = {
            title: "milan7",
            body: "dai7",
            userID: 101
        }
    let todor = await createTodo(todo);
    console.log(todor);
    console.log(await getTodo(5));
}
mainFunc()
```

Answer (score 4):

It might be useful to somebody:

I was having the issue that formdata was not being sent for my request

In my case it was a combination of following headers that were also causing the issue and the wrong Content-Type.

So I was sending these two headers with the request and it wasn't sending the formdata when I removed the headers that worked.

> ```
> "X-Prototype-Version" : "1.6.1",
> "X-Requested-With" : "XMLHttpRequest"
> ```

Also as other answers suggest that the Content-Type header needs to be correct.

For my request the correct Content-Type header was:

> "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"

So bottom line if your formdata is not being attached to the Request then it could potentially be your headers. Try bringing your headers to a minimum and then try adding them one by one to see if your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 4):

If your JSON payload contains arrays and nested objects, I would use `URLSearchParams`  and jQuery's `param()` method.

```
fetch('/somewhere', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: new URLSearchParams($.param(payload))
})
```

To your server, this will look like a standard HTML `<form>` being `POST`ed.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it even better with await/async.

The parameters of http request:

```
const _url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
let _body = JSON.stringify({
  title: 'foo',
  body: 'bar',
  userId: 1,
});
  const _headers = {
  'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
};
const _options = { method: 'POST', headers: _headers, body: _body };
```

With clean async/await syntax:

```
const response = await fetch(_url, _options);
if (response.status >= 200 && response.status <= 204) {
  let data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
} else {
  console.log(`something wrong, the server code: ${response.status}`);
}
```

With old fashion fetch().then().then():

```
fetch(_url, _options)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((json) => console.log(json));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that, we don't need parse the JSON object into a string, if the remote server accepts json into they request, just run:

```
const request = await fetch ('/echo/json', {
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
  },
  method: 'POST',
  body: { a: 1, b: 2 }
});
```

Such as the curl request

```
curl -v -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '@data.json' '/echo/json'
```

In case to the remote serve not accept a json file as the body, just send a dataForm:

```
const data =  new FormData ();
data.append ('a', 1);
data.append ('b', 2);

const request = await fetch ('/echo/form', {
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  method: 'POST',
  body: data
});
```

Such as the curl request

```
curl -v -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d '@data.txt' '/echo/form'
```

Comment: This is blatantly incorrect. It has nothing to do with the server side whether or not you need to stringify your json. That is exactly what your `curl` command is doing implicitly! If you don't stringify your objects before passing them as the `body` you will just send `"[object Object]"` as the body of your request. A simple test in Dev Tools would show you that. Open it up and try this without leaving this tab:
`a = new FormData(); a.append("foo","bar"); fetch("/foo/bar", { method: 'POST', body: {},   headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
  } })`

Answer (score 1):

You only need to check if response is ok coz the call not returning anything.

```
var json = {
    json: JSON.stringify({
        a: 1,
        b: 2
    }),
    delay: 3
};

fetch('/echo/json/', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: 'json=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(json.json)) + '&delay=' + json.delay
})
.then((response) => {if(response.ok){alert("the call works ok")}})
.catch (function (error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// extend FormData for direct use of js objects
Object.defineProperties(FormData.prototype, { 
    load: {
       value: function (d) {
                   for (var v in d) {
                      this.append(v, typeof d[v] === 'string' ? d[v] : JSON.stringify(d[v]));
                   }
               }
           }
   })

var F = new FormData;
F.load({A:1,B:2});

fetch('url_target?C=3&D=blabla', {
        method: "POST", 
          body: F
     }).then( response_handler )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [fill-fetch](https://github.com/Bert0324/fill-fetch), which is an extension of `fetch`. Simply, you can post data as below:

```
import { fill } from 'fill-fetch';

const fetcher = fill();

fetcher.config.timeout = 3000;
fetcher.config.maxConcurrence = 10;
fetcher.config.baseURL = 'http://www.github.com';

const res = await fetcher.post('/', { a: 1 }, {
    headers: {
        'bearer': '1234'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult FetchDemo(int? id)
    {
        return Json(new { DataResult = "Success" });
    }
```

### Using FormData my code works fine in ASP.NET

```
    var formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('id', 3);


    fetch("/Home/FetchDemo", {

        method: 'post',

        body: formData
    })

    .then(res => res.json())

    .then(res => console.log(res))

    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score -1):

The **fetch API** is a JavaScript function that allows devs to make HTTP requests. You can fetch (or retrieve) data, submit data, update existing data, and more. And all of this comes in a more powerful, flexible, and cleaner package than `XMLHttpRequest`.

When making these requests, we primarily deal with four types of **HTTP methods**, although there are several more:

1. **GET**: For retrieving data from the server. It doesn't change the server state.
2. **POST**: For sending data to the server, typically resulting in a change on the server.
3. **PUT**: For replacing a current resource with a new one.
4. **DELETE**: For removing a specified resource.

Note that the code samples below use `async/await` for simplicity. If you don't want to use `async/await`, you can change these examples to use the `.then()` pattern.

For a **GET** request, try this:

```js
async function getData() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.example.com/data');
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error:', error);
  }
}
getData();
```

In this block, we're retrieving data and making it available under the variable `data`.

**For POSTing JSON data**, use this:

```js
async function postData() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.example.com/data', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({key: 'value'})
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error:', error);
  }
}
postData();
```

This block POSTs JSON data to a resource. You can capture the response JSON as `data`.

(This was originally posted on my blog: https://7.dev/post-json-fetch-api/)