# Jquery Ajax Start and Stop method with fetch api

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch-api

I want to use the Jquery start and stop method to appear and disappear my spinner but I can't seem to work with jquery ajax start and stop method when im using the fetch api.
how can i walk around this ?

```
$(document)
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $buffer.show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $buffer.hide();
    })
;
fetch(url)
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(thisObj => writeOnTheScreen(thisObj))
    })
;
```

Comment: Once way you can do it, is show you spinner just before executing ur ajax calls and once it is done(ajax calls), you can hide it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37202078/ajaxstart-and-ajaxstop-equivalent-with-fetch-api

Answer (score -1):

**Try this , Its working for me:**

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    $('.ui-loader').hide();
});
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    $('.ui-loader').show();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.ui-loader').hide();
    }, 10000);
});
```

**Note: Its not working if async = false.**

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, it should work, please check the version of the jquery which you are using, and that you should bind your handler to document

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
   alert('ajax started');
});
```

You can also use a third party, [Pace](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/) is easy to implement.

Comment: I'm using fetch api as the title say not $.ajax

Comment: If you are using fetch api then you can use Promise to notify when it is completed.