# Can't send payload to back-end from front-end

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, sequelize.js

I'm making a chat bot where people get coins each 30 minutes, they can then spend those coins. When they spend those coins they need to be deducted, so I need to catch their command in my front-end and deduct the coins from their profile in my back-end.

This is a case of my switch case in which I catch the command that's being utilised

```
case `!gayOverlay`:
        const requiredKluiten = 50;

        fetch(`/api/users/${userstate.username}`) // fetch from Express.js server
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(result => {
            if (result.instakluiten >= requiredKluiten) {
              client.action(channel, `${userstate[`display-name`]}, you've got enough instakluiten for this.`);

              const method = `PATCH`;
              const payload = {requiredKluiten};
              const body = JSON.stringify(payload);
              const headers = `Content-Type: application/json`;

              return fetch(`/api/users/${userstate.username}`, {method, body, headers})
                .then(r => console.log(`Result is `, d));
            }else{
              client.action(channel, `${userstate[`display-name`]}, you don't have enough instakluiten for this, you need ${requiredKluiten - result.instakluiten} more.`);
            }
          });
        break;
```

I'm using PATCH to update my viewers' coins (I read [Please do not patch like an idiot](http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/), but people in the comments were also against the method, so I'm not sure what the correct way is anymore now...), when I send data with postman my req.body in my back-end is filled with the data I added. However, when I execute my function (which also should have data because of my payload), my req.body is an empty object. What am I doing wrong here?

This is what's happening on the server side

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/api/users/:username', (req, res) => {
  let username = req.params.username;
  findUserInApi(username)
    .then(foundUser => {
      console.log(`foundUser is ${foundUser}`);
      if (!foundUser) {
        res.status(403).send('User not found in api yet');
      }else{
        res.json(foundUser);
      }
    });
});
```

**Update**

This is what's being returned in the then after my patch (changed it to PUT after the comment of Alex) https://puu.sh/shO57/362b639545.png

**Update**

Even when trying it like this (because of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data)) it makes no difference

```
const data = JSON.stringify(payload);
const body = new FormData();
body.append(`json`, data);
```

**Update**

When using postman my body is always: {'requiredKluiten': 50}.

When I remove the headers (that were automatically set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded when choosing x-www-form-urlencoded to send my data) I get an empty object with Postman. When the headers are added again with x-www-form-urlencoded it works. When I select form-data however I get as req.body:

```
{ '------WebKitFormBoundarySAXAR2jfhUJt39US\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': '"requiredKluiten"\r\n\r\n50\r\n------WebKitFormBoundarySAXAR2jfhUJt39US--\r\n' }
```

However, when adding the headers to my code, it still doesn't work when executing my fetch... I must still be doing something wrong :/...

This is what's being executed right now, any flaws to be spotted?

```
case `!gayOverlay`:
const requiredKluiten = 50;

  fetch(`/api/users/${userstate.username}`) // fetch from Express.js server
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(result => {
            if (result.instakluiten >= requiredKluiten) {
              client.action(channel, `${userstate[`display-name`]}, you've got enough instakluiten for this.`);

              const method = `PUT`;
              const payload = {requiredKluiten};
              const body = JSON.stringify(payload);
              const headers = `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`;

              return fetch(`/api/users/${userstate.username}`, {method, body, headers})
                .then(d => console.log(`Result is `, d));
            }else{
              client.action(channel, `${userstate[`display-name`]}, you don't have enough instakluiten for this, you need ${requiredKluiten - result.instakluiten} more.`);
            }
          });
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, did you try to use the HTTP verb PUT ? It's commonly used to update entities into a REST Webservice.

Comment: And didn't saw that before, but you shouldn't compare the value you get from server with a const value client side. If I edit the requiredKluiten const in Javascript debugging, I can make you call the POST query even if I have 1 coin.

Comment: Oh that's actually a giant mistake... I shouldn't do that indeed... I put the const in my client side just to test the (requiredKluiten - currentKluiten). However, I looked up whether I should use PUT PATCH or POST. And I thought PATCH was the best way to go here. I would try PUT, but I don't _think_ that should be the solution, because via postman I get my req.body... Also, do you have any suggestion which approach would be the best to append the requiredKluiten to each command? Do I pass on the string of my command and check in my back-end: if(req.body.command === '!gayOverlay')?

Comment: @Alex the put didn't make a difference. I updated my question with a screenshot of what's being returned.

Comment: Yeah anyway it's not a big deal if you use PUT or PATCH, they're pretty the same, it's only about convention. In postman, do you have some headers set ? if it works with postman but not from your app, you should check for headers differences

Comment: I tried to be as complete as possible with my update @Alex, thanks for bearing with me so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128079/discussion-between-alex-and-kevin).