# Error while binding array to state

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to use fetch to get json data from my back end and then put it on a array, and show it on the screen, for now on the console log. 
I am trying to store the information I get back in a array called `data` which I initialized in getinistate, and then put json data in it while the fetch call is done. For now The error I am reciving is that console.log is basically empty.

Here is the code.

```
<body>
  <div id="reactBinding"></div>

<script type="text/babel">
  var Heading = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          data: [],
          amount : 1000
        };
    },
    handleChange: function(event){
      this.setState({amount : event.target.value});
    },
      loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
        var value = {
          method : 'GET' ,
          headers : {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'contentType' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
          body : ({
            amount : this.state.amount
          })
        };
          fetch('http://localhost:3000/getIOT', value)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseData) =>{
            responseData : this.state.data 
          })
          .catch(function(err){
           console.log(err);
        });
      },
      showTable : function(){
        console.log(data);
      },
      render : function(){
        var amount = this.state.amount;
        return(
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div classname="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
                <div className="text-center">
                  <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
                  <h2> {amount} </h2>
                  <input type="text" value={amount} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                  <button onClick={this.showTable}>Show Table</button>
                  <button onClick={this.loadCommentsFromServer}> Submit </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
  });
ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <Heading
      name="React JS"
      >
      </Heading>
      </div>
  , document.getElementById('reactBinding'));
</script>
</body>
```

So again, what I want to do is get the information from fetch, put it in the variable called  `data` array  and then when someone clicks `showTable`, it should `console.log` the array out. Totally new to react so need a bit of handholding since this is the first time I am writing it. If this code is a bit too messy it would be great someone could help show me how to write a simple fetch.

Also if you have time it would be great if someone could explain how can I display the array in a table. in the `showTable` part.

Comment: then((response) => response.json()) typo ?

Comment: Off topic, but if you're using babel for the JSX, why not also use it to do proper classes instead of the legacy `React.createClass`?

Comment: @VladuIonut I fixed the typo, but now I am not getting any information at all....

Comment: @ndugger: _'proper'_ classes..?

Comment: @ndugger I am not sure what you mean, since I am totally , like totally new to this. But proper classes meaning losing the React name?

Comment: @MayankShukla I mean actual ES6 classes (https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/#ecmascript-2015-features-classes) -- I would hope any JS developer would know them already.

Comment: LOL i know you guys want to hear ndugger out, but in the mean time can someone help me ? :D

Comment: @Pineda I'm referring to ES6 classes, where you would write `class Heading extends React.Component { ... }`

Comment: @ndugger: I know what you were referring to, that's why I put quote marks (') around them and made it _italic_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `setState` to store the data in `state` variable once you get the `response`, like this:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/getIOT', value)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) =>{
     //responseData : this.state.data 
     this.setState({data: responseData}); // use this line
  })
```

put the `console.log` in `render` function, it will print the data once you get the response, like this:

```
render : function(){
        var amount = this.state.amount;
        console.log('data', this.state.data);
        ....
```

**Update**:

Check the working Code:

```js
var Heading = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
          data: [],
          amount : 1000
        };
    },
    handleChange: function(event){
      this.setState({amount : event.target.value});
    },
      loadCommentsFromServer: function() {
        var value = {
          method : 'GET' ,
          headers : {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'contentType' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
          body : ({
            amount : this.state.amount
          })
        };
          fetch('http://localhost:3000/getIOT', value)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseData) =>{
            this.setState({data: responseData});
          })
          .catch(function(err){
           console.log(err);
        });
      },
      showTable : function(){
        console.log(this.state.data);
      },
      render : function(){
        var amount = this.state.amount;
        console.log('data', this.state.data);
        return(
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div classname="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
                <div className="text-center">
                  <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
                  <h2> {amount} </h2>
                  <input type="text" value={amount} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                  <button onClick={this.showTable}>Show Table</button>
                  <button onClick={this.loadCommentsFromServer}> Submit </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
  });
ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <Heading
      name="React JS"
      >
      </Heading>
      </div>
  , document.getElementById('reactBinding'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='reactBinding'></div>
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined :(

Comment: first it shows data [ ] <-- empty, then the error pops up if I click the submit

Comment: you are getting that error because use used `console.log(data)` in `showTable` method, instead of that use `console.log(this.state.data)`, check the working code :)

Comment: It works! Thanks!!, One issue though, even though its not part of the problem, when I use fetch and try to send the amount as a get request, my node js server does not receive it .... Got any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: check request header in developer tool, if amount value is proper, then your `frontend` part is ok, otherwise its a `frontend` issue.

Comment: The developer tool shows that there is no information getting passed.

Comment: check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data, may be helpful :)

Comment: is it working ? i never used fetch so don't have much idea about it :)

Comment: No dint use the link, I just added the amount to the URL instead ;) 
This is the first time I am writing with react.js and using fetch so I am just doing it the old fashioned way :D Need to learn a bit more to get writing proper codes for react :D

Comment: start your journey from this place: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/hello-world.html it will help you alot :)