# Fetch request with params

Tags: javascript, php, request, fetch

I fetch data to server, and I want to see in the console params, which i send. But on PHP side $_POST value is empty and I always recieve empty array.(WEB -> PHP -> WEB) What I do wrong ?

**JS code:**

```
function json(response){
  return response.json()
}

let data = {obj : 'value'};

fetch('http://localhost/Fetch_mysql_angular/requests.php', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then(json)
.then(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log('Request failed', error);
});
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php

  echo json_encode($_POST);

?>
```

**Console**

```
[]
```

Thanks for spending time on my post!

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data

Comment: `$_POST`: _"An **associative array of variables** passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when **using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data** as the HTTP Content-Type in the request."_

Comment: Thanks, you save my time!

Answer (score 1):

When you using **JSON.stringify(data)** your data will be encoded and sent in json format and not form-data. So php will not fill $_POST variable.

You can still get POST json data by reading  **php://input**

```
$data = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input') ) ;
var_dump( $data );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning the response in your callback.

```
function json(response){
  return response.json();
}
```

Comment: It was my mistake in post, sorry