# JavaScript Fetch() body not posting correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch-api

I'm attempting to make a POST request to a URL on my website in JavaScript.
I previously was using jQuery's [`$.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) function which sends the data object correctly as is, but when attempting to switch to the built-in [`Fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) method, I am struggling to send the data in the same form as the jQuery method.

I have the following JavaScript object:

```
let requestBody = {
    username: document.getElementById('username').value,
    password: document.getElementById('password').value,
}
```

and I'm attempting to make a `POST` request to the URL `'/user/login'`.

The following jQuery method works:

```
$.post('/user/login', requestBody);
```

[image: jQuery POST form data]

But when trying with the `Fetch` method:

```
fetch(new Request('/user/login'), { method: 'POST', body: requestBody })
```

I do not see any form body in the Chrome developer tools.
If I try to stringify the `requestBody` object:

```
fetch(new Request('/user/login'), { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(requestBody) })
```

[image: Fetch POST]

You can see I do not have any data under `Form Data` as I do with jQuery, and instead it is under `Request Payload`. The problem with this, is that it is incompatable with my already written backend code.

How can I POST a JavaScript object to a URL with `Fetch()` just as a jQuery `$.post()` would?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/29823632/3214471

Answer (score 1):

what you need is to use `FormData` instead of JSON representation

[here is how to do it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects), basically it looks like this:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("username", document.getElementById('username').value);
formData.append("password", document.getElementById('password').value);
```

Comment: The OP's `requestBody` isn't JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: I did indeed try this actually, but I got something like this instea d https://gyazo.com/1bd671205e9e6d7452319640cb8aa897

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was referring to the second example, but it may be misleading :)