# EDITED: Can't send POST request to Express server with Fetch API, keep getting JSON.parse error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to JavaScript, and am learning to develop with an Express server on Glitch.com. I am running into issues with my Fetch API POST request, where it keeps returning a JSON.parse error when I try to send it a JSON object.

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

I plan on using the JSON object to take in input from an HTML form, and I have that data saved in string variables but cannot use it. When I test JSON.stringify and JSON.parse in the console, it logs it as

```
Object { some: 1 }
```

I am also not sure where I should be directing the URL of the Fetch API, though the Express code is saved in a folder in Glitch called "server/ex.js". Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**
So it looks like I'm getting errors with my Express server, when I check the response status code it's 404. How do I find the right URL?

Comment: What exactly does the response body look like? (You can see it in the "Network" tab in your browser developer tools.) The error is from the client-side code that tries to treat the server response as JSON.

Comment: @Pointy Oh! It says: "Cannot POST /server/ex.js" does this mean it's a problem with Express? Thank you so much for the quick response btw

Comment: Right; it's a bad URL or there's no handler for a POST or something, and then your client-side code attempts to parse that error message as JSON.

Comment: @Pointy sorry hit enter too quickly, it says Cannot POST /server/ex.js

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, that's useful to know. I'm using some example code, and I'm not sure if it has a POST handler or not. I'm thinking of testing out body-parser, thank you for the help!

Comment: would be great to see the guide that you are following. my guess is 1) you are suppose to `fetch('http://HOSTNAME:PORT/server/ex.js')` or you are suppose to also write the post request handlers server side

Comment: @pandamakes now it kind of looks like Frankenstein code haha. It's hosted in Glitch, which gives you a custom URL for every project in the format "https://random-word.glitch.me". Just tried your suggestion with "https://random-word.glitch.me:3000/server/ex.js", and it's giving me "TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource"?

Comment: true, you did mention you want to develop an express server. Is this your backend code? i.e., do you have something like `const express = require('express')` etc? edit: probably easier also, if you can share any other codes + files in your current project

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
var payload = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};

var data = new FormData();
data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( payload ) );

fetch("/echo/json/",
{
    method: "POST",
    body: data
})
.then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
.then(function(data){ alert( JSON.stringify( data ) ) })
```

This code above is in: [Fetch: POST json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data)

Comment: Thanks Mateus, I tried it and it still gave me the error. In the comments above I found out that it's actually a problem with my Express server - I'm getting a 404 status code when I try to POST. Do you have any tips?

Comment: @bzrkly can you share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, here's the Express code, the sample I was looking at also used Next.js but I'm having trouble understanding it. Sorry for the newbieness on here & thanks!: 
app.post('/submit', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

const nextApp = next({ dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' });
const nextHandler = nextApp.getRequestHandler();

app.get('*', (req, res) => nextHandler(req, res));

nextApp.prepare().then(() => {

  app.listen(3000, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    }

    console.log(`listening on 3000`);
  });  
});

Comment: @bzrkly ok, I'm writing a simple example https://github.com/MateusGabi/Express-JS-Simple-Example

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you started a node project, you will want to edit the `server.js` file to include the following codes:

```
app.post('/server/ex.js',function(req,res){
  res.send(JSON.stringify({
    'hello':'world'
  }))
})
```

then the fetch request in `client.js` should return the json object

edit1) sorry, just realised it was a post request, not a get request

edit2) in order to parse the json object you sent `{some:1}`, you will need [`bodyparser` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser).

edit after seeing `server.js`:

you will need the following for `server.js` at the very top if it does not already:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
```

in addition, it will need the code snippit above somewhere later.

I am not too sure where you are getting the `next()` function from, though.

Comment: I posted the whole code section above if that helps! I'll try this, thank you!