# fetch not posting form data in zapier

Tags: node.js, zapier

I have a code in zapier:

```
var username = "username"
var password = "password"
var grant_type = "password"
var client_id = "id"
var ENDPOINT="someUrl"
var json = {
      "grant_type": grant_type,
      "username": username,
      "password": password,
      "client_id": client_id
};
var options={
  method:"POST",
  headers: {
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  payload:json
}
const result = await fetch(WAVITY_ENDPOINT,options)
const content = await result.json()
output={response:content}
```

But I am always getting Unauthorized error. I do the same through request module and it works. I think fetch is not sending the data. Any help would be appreciated.In my request module code, I have following options:

```
headers: {
        connection: "Keep-Alive",
        timeout: 5000
      },
      url: ENDPOINT,
      method: 'POST',
      formData: {
        'grant_type': grant_type,
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        'client_id': client_id
      }
```

**NOTE: Changing the headers of fetch to headers like in request also does not work for me.**

Comment: Just want a small check first that your variable for the endpoint used in fetch is the same as the variable stated at line 5 (you stated "ENDPOINT" at line 5, and then later referred to it as WAVITY_ENDPOINT)

Answer (score 1):

Per [this question about fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data), I believe the key for the data should be `body`, not `payload`.

Zapier uses `node-fetch` ([source](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch)), so if you can get it working locally with that, you'll be able to paste it into Zapier successfully.