# Can't sent json data to server with POST request

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, fetch

I am trying to send json data to server (using fetch API and PHP as a server side language). My server side code is pretty simple:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Now when I send the request simply with `"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"` like this:

```
fetch("http://localhost:80/test.php", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: "a=b"
})
.then(function(response){
    return response.text();
})
.then(function(text){
    console.log(text);
})
```

Everything works fine and the output is:

```
Array
(
    [a] => b
)
```

Now when I want to send the same thing but with JSON like this:

```
fetch("http://localhost:80/test.php", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({"a":"b"})
})
.then(function(response){
    return response.text();
})
.then(function(text){
    console.log(text);
})
```

I get the weird output of the whole array as a key:

```
Array
(
    [{"a":"b"}] => 
)
```

Now when I change the content type to: `"application/json"` in fetch call, the output is completely lost and I get the empty array:

```
Array
(
)
```

Can you tell me what the reason is? and how to achieve the desired result. (sending whole data with JSON).

Comment: possible duplicate from - take a look [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data)

Comment: @PhilS Not, just tried that and it still gives the empty output.

Comment: did you use `FormData`?

Comment: @Sakezzz yes, and that worked, but I still want to know what is the problem here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set the content-type to `application/json`:

```
fetch('http://localhost:80/test.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: JSON.stringify({a: 'b'})
});
```

and the server-side should be able to decode (there is no `$_POST` without a form's post-fields):

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
echo '<pre>'.print_r($array, true).'</pre>';
```

the `test.php` should jut send a content type header, along with the JSON:

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON should be like:
`JSON.stringify({a: 'Text Value', b: 1})`

Then in your PHP:
`print_r(json_decode($_POST));`

PHP doesn't understand JSON until you decode it.

Answer (score 1):

You code below:

```
fetch("http://localhost:80/test.php", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({"a":"b"})
})
.then(function(response){
    return response.text();
})
.then(function(text){
    console.log(text);
})
```

Should be written as:

```
fetch("http://localhost:80/test.php", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: {"a":"b"}
})
.then(function(response){
    return response.text();
})
.then(function(text){
    console.log(text);
})
```

Note:
`body: JSON.stringify({"a":"b"})` has been changed to `body: {"a":"b"}`