# Why I cannot get the passed parameters in the body section?

Tags: javascript, php

Here is my server side code: (I use Laravel framework)

```
// route
Route::post('get_login_api_token', 'Auth\LoginController@get_login_api_token')->middleware('cors');

public function get_login_api_token(Request $request){
    return $request;
}
```

And here is three kind of requests:

### #1:

```
fetch('https://back.pronexo.net/get_login_api_token', {
          method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
          mode: 'no-cors',
          body: JSON.stringify({cell_phone:'whatever', password:'whatever'}),
          headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }).then(res => console.log('OK'));
```

> returns `[]`

---

### #2:

```
fetch('https://back.pronexo.net/get_login_api_token?cell_phone=whatever&password=whatever', {
          method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
          mode: 'no-cors',
          headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        }).then(res => console.log('OK'));
```

> returns `{"cell_phone":"whatever","password":"whatever"}`

---

### #3:

[image]

---

Ok, as you can see, in the postman *(request simulator)* it works when when you pass parameters in the `body` section *(not as query string in the url)*. But why it doesn't work in the code? *(you can try it in the `console` tan of your browser)*. Any idea how can I make `#1` working ?

---

EDIT: Noted that the header is different in the postman:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch: POST json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data)

Comment: Do you use Symfony or Laravel or how does your Request method looks like?

Comment: the issue lies within your implementation of the `Request` method. please check what types of requests it supports

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use header as application/json and didn't encoded body with json format.

I have used curl and i am getting response in json and when decoded it gives

stdClass Object ( [cell_phone] => whatever [pass] => whatever )

Comment: in json format..when decoded I am getting it as
stdClass Object ( [cell_phone] => whatever [pass] => whatever )

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the POST requets is well formated ?

I think that you should test using the FormData API ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)).

```
var data = new FormData
data.append("cellphone", "whatever")
data.append("password", "whatever")

// using XMLHttpRequest
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://back.pronexo.net/get_login_api_token')
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (xhr.readystate = 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
       console.log(xhr.response, xhr.responseText)
   }
}
xhr.send(data)

// using fetch method I don't know how it deals with FormData Objects.
fetch('https://back.pronexo.net/get_login_api_token', {
      method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
      mode: 'no-cors',
      body: data,
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
}).then(res => console.log('OK'));
```

You can maybe use external tools like this: [Insomnia REST Client](https://insomnia.rest/) to test your API.