# Beginner Passport/React: login system not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I can't get this login system to work, here's my code:

React code:

```
  login(username, password) {
      fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', {
        method: 'post',
        headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password})
      }).then(res=>res.json())
        .then(res => console.log(res));
    }
```

Node backend, called by the React code:

```
app.post("/login", function(request, response) {
  passport.authenticate("local-login", function(err, user, info) {
    console.log("username: ", user)
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return response.send(false);
    }
    request.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
      checkLogIn(request, response);
      return response.send(true);
    });
  })(request, response);
});
```

And Passport.js:

```
 passport.use(
  'local-login',
  new LocalStrategy({
   usernameField : 'username',
   passwordField: 'password',
   passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, username, password, done){
   connection.query("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE username = ? ", [username],
   function(err, rows){
    if(err)
     return done(err);
    if(!rows.length){
     return done(null, false, req.send(JSON.stringify({ logged: "NO" })));
    }
    if(!bcrypt.compareSync(password, rows[0].password))
     return done(null, false, req.send(JSON.stringify({ logged: "NO" })));

    return done(null, rows[0]);
   });
  })
 );
```

No matter what credentials I put in, I am getting 'False' in the Chrome console. This 'False' comes from the Node backend, this line:

> if (!user) {
>           return response.send(false);
>   }

As you can see I am also console logging the username in the Node backend, and here's what I get from this command:

> username:  false

What should I modify in order to console log the user's username if his credentials are correct, and console log an error message when it's incorrect?

Cheers!

Comment: You're trying to send inside the `LocalStrategy`, using `req.send` (which doesn't exist). Use this instead: `return done(null, false, { logged: "NO" });` (you can access that data via `info` in your route handler) Also double check that username and password are correct, and that your columns are called `username` and `password`.

Comment: user & pass are correct, and the columns name are indeed username & password. I just changed this line and it didn't do anything..... :( When I console log the 'info' in the node backend, it gives me `[0] username:  { message: 'Missing credentials' }`

Comment: I can't replicate this because `user` being `false` suggests that the code tries to call `req.send()`, and this crashes node for me. Since you are getting `false` as a reply from the server, the only explanation I can see is that either the query returns zero rows, or `bcrypt.compareSync` returns false. Just put `console.log()`s all over the place and double check that variables actually contain what you think they contain, and functions return what you think they return.