# Read Ajax post data in django

Tags: python, ajax, django, es6-promise

I got an Ajax request using [promise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42493030/2263683) in my django project:

```
var path = window.location.pathname;
fetch('/getblogs/', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({'path': path})
}).then(function (response) {
  return response.json();
});
```

The request is in a `js` file and there is no form.

I'm trying to read data in my `views.py` like this:

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_blogs(request):
    cat_id = request.POST.get('path')
    print("RESULT: " + str(cat_id))
```

But in output I get:

```
RESULT: None
```

Am I missing somthing in reading post data or there is something wrong with my ajax request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try like this:

```
import json

@csrf_exempt
def get_blogs(request):
    cat_id = json.loads(request.body).get('path')
    print("RESULT: " + str(cat_id))
```

Comment: I should've gone for body not post. This solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST)

> HttpRequest.POST
>
> A dictionary-like object containing all given HTTP POST parameters,
> providing that the request contains form data. See the QueryDict
> documentation below. If you need to access raw or non-form data posted
> in the request, access this through the HttpRequest.body attribute
> instead.

Try using `json.loads(request.body)['path']`