# Add parameters to post request using js on client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, post, request

I'm developing a "TODO" app using node.js and mongodb.

I'm trying to post a new task from the client but I didn't success to pass parameters to the server and from there to the database.

Client code:

```
 <script>
  function addData(item, url) {
    var text = document.getElementById("myTask").value;
     return fetch('/todos',{
      method: 'post',
      body: text
            }).then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data));
  }
</script>
```

Server code:

```
    app.post('/todos',(req,res) =>{
  console.log("\n\n req.body is:  \n\n",req.body);
  var todo = new Todo({
    text: req.body.text});
    todo.save().then((doc) =>{
      res.send(doc);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(doc,undefined,2));
    },(err) =>{
      res.status(400).send(err); //400 = unable to connect
      console.log("Unable to save todo.\n\n\n" , err);
    });
  });
```

And the problem is that the client doesn't send the body to the server, 
and the body is null on the server side:
[See the logs here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EU2b.png)
(as you can see: req.body = {})
In the js code, I tried to pass the body parameter but I guess I did something wrong so I want to know the best way to pass parameters back to the server (not only the body but text, time and etc)

Thank in advance,
Sagiv

Comment: Do you parsing body of post request?

Comment: What do you mean? I just try to add data to my request, but as you can see in the screen-shot the request is {}.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are missing something. Try to use name of param

```
body: JSON.stringify({data: text})
```

OR

read here [Fetch: POST json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data)

Comment: I think stringify isn't necessary if you have simple string, but always good practice

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.
I've already tried to solve it by myself and I tried all the solutions on the post you attached.
`
      function addData() {

      var textData = {
          text: document.getElementById("myTask").value
      };

      var data = new FormData();
      data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( textData ) );
      fetch('/todos',
      {
          method: "POST",
          body: data
      })
      .then(function(res){return res.json();})
      .then(function(data){alert( JSON.stringify( data ) ) })
}`
I tried this code but still, the request in {}

Comment: I succeeded, I had to use async. (this code works for me) : 

(async () => {
  const rawResponse = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 'Textual content'})
  });
  const content = await rawResponse.json();

  console.log(content);
})();

thanks.

Comment: my congratulations :)

Answer (score 0):

I used this code:

```
(async () => {
  const rawResponse = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 'Textual content'})
  });
  const content = await rawResponse.json();

  console.log(content);
})();
```

and now I succeeded to pass data to the request.
Thanks everybody