# How to create records in database without form upon key press

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am using Rails and I am building a page that creates new "people"(people/new).
Using javascript, I scan a page with user inputs and i end up with a javascript object looking like this:

```
obj = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };
```

I want to add an event listener (keypress q) that saves this hash into the database, which looks like this:

```
  create_table "people", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "age"
    t.string "city"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Even though i have inputs that i scan, there IS NO form.

I know how to JSON.stringify and I know how eventListeners work but I am unsure how I can send that stringified object from javascript to ruby code that saves it to the database.

Here is the Javascript i have done so far :
app/assets/javascript/testing.js

```
addEventListener('keyup', event => {
    if (event.key === "q") {
        var array = []
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input")
        inputs.forEach ((input) => {
            array.push(input.value)
        })
        var name = array[0]
        var age = array[1]
        var city = array[2]

        var hash = {}
        hash["name"]= name
        hash["age"]= age
        hash["city"]= city
        var stringified = JSON.stringify(hash)
    }
} )
```

And here is what my controller looks like :

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @people = Person.all
  end

  def new
    @person = Person.new
  end

  def create
    Person.create(person_params)
  end

  private

  def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age, :city)
  end
end
```

What I expect is that when the "q" key is pressed, whatever is present in the inputs is saved to the database

Comment: Make a POST request to the backend, just as the form would do. PS: What will you do with people living in Quebec? Or people called Quinten? Since they will post non complete data while typing in their name if you tie the POST to pressing the letter Q.

Comment: Need to submit form on keypress `$('#form_id').submit();`

Comment: @Shilly And how do you think I should do it? I cannot use the POST attribute of forms though, as I have no form, and I still have the problem that I have a stringified variable i cannot use...

Comment: Since you tagged the question ajax, use an ajax call. :)

Comment: I will look into it, thx

Answer (score 1):

```
addEventListener('keyup', event => {
    if (event.key === "q") {
        var array = []
        var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input")
        inputs.forEach ((input) => {
            array.push(input.value)
        })
        var name = array[0]
        var age = array[1]
        var city = array[2]

        var hash = {}
        hash["name"]= name
        hash["age"]= age
        hash["city"]= city
        var stringified = JSON.stringify(hash)

        // Using Javascript
        fetch('/people', {
           method: 'POST',
           user_params: stringified
        })
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function (data) {
          console.log(data)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
           console.log(error)
        })                    
    }
} )
```

peoples_controller.rb

```
  def create
    Person.create(name: params[:user_params][:name], age: params[:user_params][:name], city: params[:user_params][:city])
  end
```

Comment: Will only work if the OP uses JQuery. Basic xmlhttp or fetch() are the alternatives.

Comment: @Shilly Yep Right.

Comment: @SilentCity Hi, are you using jquery ? i'm not much familiar with javascript ajax syntax :)

Comment: @Gabbar I am pretty sure I am not using JQuery

Comment: @SilentCity Alright, you can give try as answer is modified with javascript syntax of ajax call.

Comment: @SilentCity Here you can get ajax call using fetch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data

Comment: Here is what the console is telling me: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity)` `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`and the terminal : `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):` I will look into Gabbar`s answer as well

Comment: @SilentCity `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token , only: [:create]` use this in people controller as first line.

Comment: @Gabbar `undefined method 'skip_before_filter' for PeopleController:Class Did you mean? skip_before_action` I am using Rails 5.2.2

Comment: using skip_before_action instead of skip_before_filter gives slightly different error as before `POST http://localhost:3000/people 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: @SilentCity It should be `skip_before_action`

Comment: @Gabbar, I have tried this and got the error : `POST http://localhost:3000/people 500 (Internal Server Error)` Terminal : `NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):`

Comment: `Started POST "/people" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-01-14 13:07:40 +0100
Processing by PeopleController#create as */*
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


  
NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
  
app/controllers/people_controller.rb:16:in `create'
`

Comment: @SilentCity Hmm data's are not sending to controller.

Comment: I think I had a problem in the controller `params[:user_params][:age]` should be `params[:user_params[:age]]` which gives me another error `TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):`so I added the `.to_i` method at the end which brings the same error message