# simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, encoding, server

I am trying to call API from postman but I am getting an error in my console.
In the below code, I am trying to decode it and process further according to it.

**API- https://localhost:5005/abc/xyz**
**Method- POST**

**Data - {"q":"hi"}**

> server.py

```
 def request_parameters(request):
    if request.method.decode('utf-8', 'strict') == 'GET':
        return {
            key.decode('utf-8', 'strict'): value[0].decode('utf-8',
                                                           'strict')
            for key, value in request.args.items()}
    else:
        content = request.content.read()
        try:
            return json.loads(content.decode('utf-8', 'strict'))
        except ValueError as e:
            logger.error("Failed to decode json during respond request. "
                         "Error: {}. Request content: "
                         "'{}'".format(e, content))
            raise
```

> Full stacktrace

```
     Failed to decode json during respond request. Error: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0). Request content: 'b'''
2019-05-14 18:21:53+0530 [-] Unhandled Error
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\server.py", line 258, in render
            body = resrc.render(self)
          File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\klein\resource.py", line 210, in render
            d = defer.maybeDeferred(_execute)
          File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 151, in maybeDeferred
            result = f(*args, **kw)
          File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\klein\resource.py", line 204, in _execute
            **kwargs)
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 151, in maybeDeferred
            result = f(*args, **kw)
          File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\klein\app.py", line 128, in execute_endpoint
            return endpoint_f(self._instance, *args, **kwargs)
          File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\klein\app.py", line 227, in _f
            return _call(instance, f, request, *a, **kw)
          File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\klein\app.py", line 50, in _call
            result = f(*args, **kwargs)
          File "server.py", line 61, in parse
            request_params = request_parameters(request)
          File "server.py", line 22, in request_parameters
            return json.loads(content.decode('utf-8', 'strict'))
          File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\json\__init__.py", line 205, in loads
            return _json.loads(s, **kwargs)
          File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py", line 535, in loads
            return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)
          File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 370, in decode
            obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
          File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
            return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
        simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

> script.js

```
function respond(msg) {
data = {
    query: msg //msg is getting from chatbot
}
fetch(`${url}/conversations/default/respond`, {
    mode: 'no-cors',
    method: 'POST',
    // dataType:'jsonp',
    q: data,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },

})
```

Comment: Ok, the error actually occurs on line `return json.loads(content.decode('utf-8', 'strict'))`. According to your source, the value of `content` should have been logged. Can you share it? The error occurs at the beginning, so you are probably trying to decode something which is not in Json format.

Comment: In content I got this  `b'{\n\t"q":"hi"\n\t\n}'`

Comment: That's weird, because when I feed that into my Json parser it gives me back `{'q': 'hi'}`. I cannot reproduce, so I cannot help.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, when I am trying to send request from browser its, is giving me an error and now from postman it working fine. I think you are right it is not in JSON format. In content, now I am getting this `b' '` 
I have added my front end code above please check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193329/discussion-between-sheel-and-serge-ballesta).

Comment: I can confirm that decoding an empty string gives that error. But I cannot help you more because now you must identify why you get an empty string there...

Comment: Why are you using `q: data` to init the `fetch` in JS?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch

I think it does not anything . You should use `body: JSON.stringify`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data

Answer (score -1):

You can get the content directly in json with `request.get_json()`

Comment: I tried `request.get_json()` and `request.json()`
but got error like this
`AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'json'`