# Axios post sending body but body is undefined with fetch and Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, fetch, postman

I'm not able to send a post body with fetch or Postman, but I can send the body with Axios.

Axios returns: `User name = Fred, password is Flintstone`

But Postman and fetch both return `User name = undefined, password is undefined`

How can I get the post body with fetch and postman?

### Server File

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const axios = require("axios");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  var user_name = req.body.user;
  var password = req.body.password;
  console.log("User name = " + user_name + ", password is " + password);
  res.end("yes");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Started on PORT 3000");
});
```

### Axios

```js
axios.post("http://localhost:3000/login", {
  user: "Fred",
  password: "Flintstone",
});
```

### Fetch (client side)

```js
fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({ user: "Fred", password: "Flintstone" }),
  mode: "no-cors",
});
```

### Postman

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch` doesn't default to posting JSON, which is why you had to encode the body explicitly. You also need to *tell* the server that you are sending JSON.

You can't do that without permission from CORS, so you **must not** set the mode to `no-cors`.

```
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({ user: "Fred", password: "Flintstone" }),
  headers
});
```

The problem with Postman is probably the same (but not visible in the UI screenshot): You need to set the Content-Type header.

Comment: thanks. This worked combined with installing cors: `npm i cors` and adding `const cors = require("cors"); app.use(cors());` to the server file.

Answer (score 2):

In Postman you are trying to send JSON data as a text. Change the type of data sent from `Text` (what you have now) to `JSON` in **Postman**.

[image]

Also as a suggestion, you should leave 1 `bodyParser` in your `server` file

For `fetch()` I recommend you to take a look at this question, some adjustments must be made [Fetch: POST json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data)

Comment: Thanks this solved my postman issue. And yea I wasn't sure about the bodyparser, thanks.

Comment: No problem, also try using `const` and `let` instead of `var` :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  var user_name = req.body.user;
  var password = req.body.password;
  console.log("User name = " + user_name + ", password is " + password);
  res.json({ "user name": user_name, "password": password });
});
```

Comment: Still got the same problem, and it also isn't sent back in the response.