# How to post values from reactjs to expressJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

My Front-end Code:-

```
const [stocks, setStocks] = useState([

    {
        "name": "TSLA"
    },
    {
        "name": "AAPL"
    },
    {
        "name": "AMZN"
    }
])


useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:2701/' , {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(stocks)
        })
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result)
        })
        .then((info) => { console.log(info); })
})
```

My Back-end Code:-

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    var data = req.body.data;
    console.log("Data:-", data)
})
```

I want to send values from reactjs to nodejs server, if possible can anyone suggest using axios

Comment: but what is the problem? are you getting any errors?

Comment: I am getting undefined value

Comment: Do you have any middleware to parse the body? Is the client making the wrong request, or is the server handling it wrongly? Find out and give a [mre] of the appropriate side.

Comment: are you using body-parser or JSON parser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch: POST json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data)

Comment: Yes, I am using cors... and also body-parser.. The values which I pass from the back-end  is able to read but value going from front-end is not able to

Answer (score 0):

Pls try the code below.

```
import axios from 'Axios';
...
    axios.post('http://localhost:2701/').then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: And what do you think this will fix, exactly?

Comment: This gives him a snippet of code to use axios.

Comment: But what does that *fix*? Are you trying to say that fetch can't do what they want (it can)? This isn't even correct use of axios to post data, because you've included no data.

Comment: OP is using `fetch` API, why suggesting a different package ?