# how do i stop req.body from being empty. node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cmd, localhost

I have a simple express app that gets one fetch request, the fetch
looks like this:

```
let opts = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  mode: "no-cors",
  body: {
    "test": "test"
  }
}

fetch("http://localhost:3001/data", opts)
```

and it's in the setup() function.

the serverside code looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen(3001, () => console.log("listening at 3001"));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/data", (req, res) => {
  console.log("post recived");
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

in my console what I get after refreshing everything is this:

```
listening at 3001
post recived
{}
```

the body of the post is not undefined but it is empty, I cannot figure out what the problem is for the life of me

Comment: runnable snippets are for  snippets that can be executed inside browsers. please format your code by wrapping it with tripple ticks (```) next time

Comment: You need to make the body a string as well as set the right headers, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/29775797/3001761

Answer (score 0):

## Problem one: no-cors

`mode: "no-cors",` is a declaration that you are not going to do anything which requires permission from CORS and that any CORS related errors should be suppressed.

You **need** permission from CORS in order to set an `application/json` content-type header.

So the first job is to **remove that line**.

---

## Problem two: CORS

Then you need to change the server so it grants you permission to make the request.

Install [the `cors` middleware package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) and follow the setup instructions there.

Make sure you [enable support for preflight requests](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight) because setting an `application/json` content-type header requires a preflight.

---

## Problem three: JSON

You claim you are sending JSON, but you are passing `fetch` a plain object.

When you do that, `fetch` will convert it to a string using the built-in `toString` method. This gives you `"[object Object]"` which is not JSON and doesn't contain your data.

You need to pass JSON instead.

```
body: JSON.stringify({
   "test": "test"
})
```

Comment: what should i put instead of '/products/:id'?

Comment: The path you want to enable CORS for