# How can I grab a div in PHP that's in a loop within a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

Below is the code.

under the function there is a `resultContainer.innerHTML` that populates a list of QR codes scanned. How can $_POST the values in PHP so that I can send it in an email format? I tried adding a name within the div (`<div **name="qrOutput"**>[${countResults}] - ${qrCodeMessage}</div>`) but PHP does not pick it up. Only returns an empty string.

I also tried giving the **`<div id="qr-reader-results"></div>`** element a name but because the output is within another div inside this div I also got an empty result.

Thanks a lot for any help.

```
<!-- start -->
<div id="qr-reader" style="width:500px"></div>
<div id="qr-reader-results"></div>


<div id="root"></div>
<script>
  function docReady(fn) {
    // see if DOM is already available
    if (document.readyState === "complete" ||
      document.readyState === "interactive") {
      // call on next available tick
      setTimeout(fn, 1);
    } else {
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
    }
  }

  docReady(function() {
    var resultContainer = document.getElementById('qr-reader-results');
    var lastResult, countResults = 0;

    function onScanSuccess(qrCodeMessage) {
      if (qrCodeMessage !== lastResult) {
        ++countResults;
        lastResult = qrCodeMessage;
        resultContainer.innerHTML += ***`<div">[${countResults}] - ${qrCodeMessage}</div>`;***
      }
    }

    var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
      "qr-reader", {
        fps: 10,
        qrbox: 250
      });
    html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess);
  });
</script>
<p id="QRout"></p>
```

Comment: possible to share the url where this code is implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your results in an other variable when you add it to the DOM.

1. Declare a variable to store your results

```js
var myResults = [];
```

2. When you add the result to the DOM add also the results in array variable

```js
// ...
resultContainer.innerHTML += `<div>[${countResults}] - ${qrCodeMessage}</div>`;
myResults.push({count: countResults, message: qrCodeMessage})
```

3. Then you can use `myResult` var on a POST request

```js
myCustomPostFunction('/yourUrl/', myResult);
```

The "myCustomPostFunction" will depend on the way you want to send the data

Check this codepen: https://codepen.io/zecka/pen/VwKNpze

#### Post request like a form submit

If you want to send the data to the current page like a form post, you can find an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/133997/2838586

#### Post request to a rest api

[Fetch: POST json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data)

Comment: If answer is ok for you, you can mark it as "accepted answer"