# POST action from Javascript throwing Access Control Error

Tags: javascript

So ORIGINALLY I think it worked and I don't think I modified it.
By it I mean a JS script that posts data to an external site. Now in my console it shows
"[01/Jun/2021 20:31:17] "POST /newCheckout HTTP/1.1" 405 -" error

Code is:

```js
let data = {"checkout_id": document.documentElement.innerHTML};

      fetch("https://botach-test-branch.ngrok.io/newCheckout", {
        method: "POST", 
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }).then(res => {
        console.log("Request complete! response:", res);
      });
```

Comment: So what is it that you want to know? The reason why its throwing an error?

Comment: 405 means action not allowed, so it's either the POST request or the OPTIONS preflight req. No way to diagnose much else with the information provided. It's not clear what kind of help is expected.

Comment: If you're trying to post JSON, you're missing `headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" }`

Comment: @Phil where would I add that? Thanks btw!

Comment: @Oze see [Fetch: POST JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data)

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, somewhere in your code, you are doing

```
headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","true")
```

This will require the server to support OPTIONS method and  will throw a 405 if it doesn't.

Comment: I am on an eCommerce platform, so idk what they have. How do I solve this?

Comment: @Oze Have you checked if that API supports  POST? May  be it is PUT instead.

Comment: It worked earlier today! I even tried the same code from earlier and it seems something just broke..

Comment: Then something changed on the server

Comment: This is BigCommerce