# How to post an array of objects to a Node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

How does one post an array of objects containing user data to the server where it can be verified?
I am trying to get data from an orderform to pass through to a server to be verified and then displayed on another page I redirect to.

```
const addProducts = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let products = [];
    for(let k = 0; k < counter+1; k++) {

    let bund = 'Bundled' + k;
    let sing = 'Single' + k;
        let unit = 'BundledUnits' + k;
        let name = 'ProductTitle' + k;
        let quant = 'Quantity' + k;
        let lPrice = 'ListPrice' + k;
        let instruct = 'Instructions' + k;

 if(document.getElementById(asin)) {
    if(document.getElementById(bund) && document.getElementById(bund).checked) {
        if(document.getElementById(unit).value) {
            let bundProduct = {
            id: k.value,
                        "Bundled": "true",
                        "Product": document.getElementById(name).value,
                        "quantity": document.getElementById(quant).value,
                        "ListPrice": document.getElementById(lPrice).value,
                        "Instructions": document.getElementById(instruct).value
                    };


                    products.push(bundProduct);
                }
            }

  else if(document.getElementById(sing) && document.getElementById(sing).checked) {
                let singProduct = {
                    id: k.value,
                    "Bundled": "false",
                    "Product": document.getElementById(name).value,
                    "quantity": document.getElementById(quant).value,
                    "ListPrice": document.getElementById(lPrice).value,
                    "Instructions": document.getElementById(instruct).value
                };
               

                products.push(singProduct);
            }
        }
        console.log(k);
    }


    let order = sessionStorage.setItem('order', JSON.stringify(products));
```

Comment: JSON.stringify it? You can send it as a buffer and convert it to string less computation in some regards.

Comment: I generally will run a POST in express, and when it's called, check the body on the client side I will via JS bypass defaults of a form and manually submit it with the body, but know it doesn't need JSON conversion in this format. It's all url encoded/decoded if your project is set properly. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fetch` or libraries like `axios`.

Check this question how to do a POST request with fetch:
[Fetch: POST JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data)

Example POST request function with `axios`:

```
const sendToServer = async (products) => {
    try {
      // store response in variable if needed
      const res = await axios.post(
        "/your_api/products",
        products  // products you want to post
      );
      // return data in case
      return res.data
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
// implement this function where you need it
sendToServer(products)
```

or check POST examples in the `axios` documentation:
https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example

```
// Send a POST request
axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });

// Send a POST request
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/user/12345',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  }
});
```