# Send Json object and receive the response at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, json

For a school project, I am to send JSON. The server processes this file and sends me back a response with a JSON. The whole thing should happen with JavaScript. I have now become aware of the `XMLHttpRequest`, but don't quite understand it.

Do I have to create two objects with GET and POST or is it possible to combine them?

At the moment I have one `var httpPost = new XMLHttpRequest();` to send and one to receive `var httpGet = new XMLHttpRequest();`

Comment: Consider using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead?

Comment: Should it then look like this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data

Answer (score 0):

let's do it with jQuery AJAX api:

```
let json = {"key":"val"}
$.post("api.php",json, function(response){
    console.log(response)
});
```

let's do it with Fetch api:

```
const data = { username: 'example' };
fetch('api.php', { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(data) })
.then(response => {
  console.log('Success:', response);
})
```