# JS Fetch and save data from response

Tags: javascript, json, variables, response, fetch-api

I´m refering to this post: [Fetch: POST JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data)

I´ve copied the code which is linked down below.

My question is, is it possible to save for example "Content-Length" which i get as a response in the JSON-file as a variable with which i can continue to work?

Looking forward!
Thanks already!

```
fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({a: 7, str: 'Some string: &=&'})
}).then(res => res.text())
  .then(res => console.log(res));
```

And my result is:

```
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "{\"a\":7,\"str\":\"Some string: &=&\"}",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Accept-Encoding": "br, gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language": "*",
    "Content-Length": "32",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
    "User-Agent": "undici",
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6388fb1d-3f7791960bdce04f36356182"
  },
  "json": {
    "a": 7,
    "str": "Some string: &=&"
  },
  "origin": "79.208.157.109",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can - just access it and store it in a variable:

```js
const example = async() => {
  const res = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({a: 7, str: 'Some string: &=&'})
  })
  const response = await res.json()
  const contentLength = response.headers['Content-Length'];
  displayContentLength(contentLength);
}

function displayContentLength(length) {
    console.log('The content length is: ' + length);
}

example();
```

Comment: FWIW: it's not necessary to access/parse the body (e.g. `res.json()`) in order to get a header value — just wanted to point out that the tasks are unrelated.

Comment: Ok thanks, it seems that I´m on the right way with your code! Just one last question, when I´ve got a structure like the following:

{
  "devices": [
    {
      "deviceid": "...",
      "lastseen": ...,
      "lowbattery": false,
      "measurement": {
        "idx": ...,
        "ts": ...,
             }
    }
  ],
  "success": true
}

I access it like response.devices.measurement['idx'];? Is that correct?

Comment: It was not 100% correctly from me, I receive the following as a response:

{
  devices: [
    {
      deviceid: '...',
      lastseen: ...,
      lowbattery: false,
      measurement: [Object]
    }
  ],
  success: true
}

I want to try to access now data which are saved in the [Object]