# how to submit a form in react native and submit to a post api

Tags: react-native

I want to save the values from all input fields to `getdata()`, but I am getting undefined value

```
export default function Signupfor(props) {
  // const phoneInput = useRef < PhoneInput > null;
  const [text, setTextname] = useState();
  function getdata() {
    console.log('dsd');
    console.log(text);
  }

  const {userInfo, log} = props?.route?.params;
  console.log(log.name);
  return (
    <View style={styles.prheight}>
      <View style={styles.form}>
        <Text style={styles.r}>One Last Step</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.forminput}
          label="Name"
          value={userInfo.user.name}
          onChangeText={text => setTextname(text)}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.forminput}
          label="Email"
          value={userInfo.user.email}
          onChangeText={text => setTextemail(text)}
        />

        <TextInput
          style={styles.forminput}
          label="Whatsapp Number"
          keyboardType="numeric"
          value={userInfo.user.number}
          onChangeText={text => setTextnumber(text)}
          // value={this.state.myNumber}
          maxLength={10} //setting limit of input
        />
       
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonw}>
        <Button color="#7743DB" title="Lets Go" onPress={() => getdata()} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Here, `name` and `email` should not be able to be edited. I want to pass the value from `value={userInfo.user.name}` to the `getdata()`

Comment: Here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: @JuniusL. pls help with a better answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch: POST JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data)

Comment: my question is how to get each value from each inputs to getdata()

Comment: @JuniusL. pls help me with the code what i have to change

Comment: there's the code in that link

Comment: pls write a answer so i can try it

Comment: did you check my answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74712807/8079868

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original method doesn't populate the state unless you edit the text input field, this is because your initialState doesn't have a value to start with. so firing `getData()` is reading empty state if the fields havent been changed.

`onChangeText={text => setTextname(text)}`
Only fire if you edit the textInput field.

Also I think you might be missing props, so first check if you are getting the correct data from `props` by logging it.

Once you have confirmed the props are available.

Set the initialState for name to `userInfo.user.name`

```
const { userInfo } = props?.route?.params;
const [name, setName] = useState(userInfo.user.name);
```

Then pass the state `name` to your TextInput and it should populate the value by reading from state.

```
return (
  <>
    <TextInput
      placeholder="name"
      value={name}
      onChangeText={(text) => setName(text)}
    />
    <Button title="Submit" onPress={() => getData()} />
  </>
)
```

Make sure to create states for any additional values you wish to save.

```
const [name, setName] = useState(userInfo.user.name);
const [email, setEmail] = useState(userInfo.user.email);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use [formik](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formik) package for making form in react native

### Installation

```
yarn add formik
```

### Usage

```js
import { Formik } from "formik";

export default function Signupfor(props) {

  const { userInfo, log } = props?.route?.params;
  console.log(log.name);
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        name: userInfo.user.name,
        email: userInfo.user.email,
        number: userInfo.user.number,
      }}
      onSubmit={async (values, actions) => {
        try {
           console.log("name", values.name);
          console.log("phone", values.number);
          
          const params = {
            full_name: values.name,
            email: values.email,
            phone_number: values.number,
          };

         
        } catch (error) {
          let message = error.message;
          console.log(message)
        } finally {
          actions.setSubmitting(false);
        }
      }}
    >
      {({
        handleChange,
        setFieldValue,
        handleSubmit,
        values,
        errors,
        touched,
        isSubmitting,
      }) => (
        <View style={styles.prheight}>
          <View style={styles.form}>
            <Text style={styles.r}>One Last Step</Text>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.forminput}
              label="Name"
              value={values.name}
              onChangeText={handleChange("name")}
            />
            <TextInput
              style={styles.forminput}
              label="Email"
              value={values.email}
              onChangeText={handleChange("email")}
            />

            <TextInput
              style={styles.forminput}
              label="Whatsapp Number"
              keyboardType="numeric"
              value={values.number}
              onChangeText={handleChange("number")}
              // value={this.state.myNumber}
              maxLength={10} //setting limit of input
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.buttonw}>
            <Button
              color="#7743DB"
              title="Lets Go"
              onPress={() => handleSubmit()}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like https://react-hook-form.com to check an example with react native on video.
Or you can right it yourself, in the example below any time you need access to input values you can read it from `text` and `number`

```js
const UselessTextInput = () => {
  const [text, onChangeText] = useState("Useless Text");
  const [number, onChangeNumber] = useState(null);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChangeText}
        value={text}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChangeNumber}
        value={number}
        placeholder="useless placeholder"
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Comment: This does not remotely address the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this!!

```
export default function Signupfor(props) {
const {userInfo, log} = props?.route?.params;
  const [name, setName] = useState(userInfo?.user?.name);
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState(userInfo?.user?.number);

  function getdata() {
    console.log("name",name)
    console.log("phone",phone)
  }
     
  return (
    <View style={styles.prheight}>
      <View style={styles.form}>
        <Text style={styles.r}>One Last Step</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.forminput}
          label="Name"
         // this value must be same with useState
          value={name}
          onChangeText={text => setName(text)}
        />    
        <TextInput
           style={styles.forminput}
           label="Mobile"
           value={phone}
           onChangeText={text => setPhone(text)}
         />      
      </View>
      <View style={styles.buttonw}>
        <Button color="#7743DB" title="Lets Go" onPress={() => getdata()} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Same goes for `email`.

Comment: value={name} does not display my name

Comment: Then you have to check that name is coming from route or not.
Please share the log of userInfo.