# Is there a way to send data from a js file to the express server without using a form?

Tags: javascript, html, database, express, ejs

I am new here, Sorry if I miss something from the best practices.

I'm creating a sudoku game, using **express**, js, html and mongoDb.

Now I'm trying to create a statistics system. I would like to send a data when you wins the sudoku, to the express server (**server.js**) and after update the mongoDb.

I know I can send a data with the POST method, but I only know using the form html, but in this case I want to send it by the function js.

The js file: **game.js**

```js
let cells = document.querySelectorAll('.div-cell'); // get the cells of the sudoku board

function checkWin() {
    const db = getDb() // get the localStorage db (there is sudoku informationo, like the solution)
    curentBoard = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
            if (cells[i].textContent === '') { // check if the cell is blank
            curentBoard += '-'
        } else {
            curentBoard += cells[i].textContent
        }
    }

    if (curentBoard === db.solution) { //check if the board is equal the solution
        // Here would be the code to send the data to the server
        alert('You won!')
        newGame()
    }
}
```

I've tried to use export to send the function to the **server.js**, to change the information, but I can't because the **game.js** is linked to the **game.html**, and for some reason the export doesn't work. Also for import.

I also tried to use **ejs** files, I rendered the **ejs** file sending the data statistics, by the **server.js** (express) but I couldn't change any data in the **ejs** file.

Then I tried to research other methods to make this, but I didn't find anything

Is there a way to send a data to the **server.js** by that function?

Comment: you could use fetch api to send a post request to your backend by adding the data to body attribute or setup a web socket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of sending a post request with some data to the backend then sending back a response data from backend to frontend.

```js
//front end

fetch('api/server', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      myData: "test"
    })
  })
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    if (data.status == 'success') {
      //when data is returned from backend
      const response = data.response
      console.log(response) //should print dataReceived
    }
  })
```

```js
//backend

const handler = async(req, res) => {
  //accessing data sent from front end
  const body = req.body
  //should print test
  console.log(body.myData)

  //returning data back to frontend
  return res.json({
    status: 'success',
    response: 'dataRecieved'
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me a lot! Your answer was really clear! Only one thing If someone else needs, "const body = JSON.parse(req.body)" It has to change to "const body = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body))".

Comment: @Glizer accually you don't need to ```stringify``` then ```parse``` it. If you remove the ```JSON.parse``` and just make it ```const body = req.body``` it should work. I have updated my code. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use fetch API inside your function to send POST request to your server. You need to send the data in the format that server expects (e.g. JSON)

here is an example of sending post request using fetch()

https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/fetch-api/fetch-post.html

for more details about fetch API see :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

or this thread :
[Fetch: POST JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data)