# What is the node js equivalent of this curl command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, fetch-api

I have this curl command that I need to write in node js:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://image.adobe.io/pie/psdService/renditionCreate \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"  \
  -H "x-api-key: $apiKey" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
  "inputs":[
    {
      "href":"<SIGNED_GET_URL>",
      "storage":"<storage>"
    }
  ],
  "outputs":[
    {
      "href":"<SIGNED_POST_URL1>",          
      "width": 512,
      "storage":"<storage>",
      "type":"image/jpeg"      
    },
    {
      "href":"<SIGNED_POST_URL2>",
      "storage":"<storage>",
      "type":"image/png"
    }
  ]
}'
```

I don't understand how to write it, specifically the input and output section.

What I have so far:

```
var url = "https://image.adobe.io/pie/psdService/renditionCreate"
var options = {method: "post"};
options.headers = { 
    Authorization: `Bearer $token`,
    x-api-key: `$apiKey`,
    Content-Type: application/json
}
options.body = {
  "inputs":[
    {
      "href":"<SIGNED_GET_URL>",
      "storage":"<storage>"
    }
  ],
  "outputs":[
    {
      "href":"<SIGNED_POST_URL1>",          
      "width": 512,
      "storage":"<storage>",
      "type":"image/jpeg"      
    },
    {
      "href":"<SIGNED_POST_URL2>",
      "storage":"<storage>",
      "type":"image/png"
    }
  ]
}

var results = await fetch(url, options);
```

The code example is from [here](https://developer.adobe.com/photoshop/photoshop-api-docs/code-sample/#create-a-document-rendition)

Update: I've got the call to work and will post it later.

Comment: What version of Node.js? Surely you've tried a little more than just `var;`

Comment: From Node.js v18 you can use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch). See [Fetch: POST JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29775797/283366)

Comment: The data would be an object with the two arrays. I’d consider searching the web for how to make a POST request in node, maybe a separate search for how to add headers.

Comment: @Phil updated with

Comment: You're simply missing `JSON.stringify()` for the `body` and quotes around `x-api-key` and `content-type`

Comment: Why separate chunks for the different parts of `options`? Invalid JS names as object keys need to be quoted. Maybe a JS tutorial would also be helpful (and likely faster).

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm following the code example here https://developer.adobe.com/photoshop/photoshop-api-docs/code-sample/#create-a-document-rendition. That's the part I'm getting confused on. I don't know how to format the inputs and outputs

Comment: Who is voting to re-open this question? It's just a typo problem at this stage and can remain closed. There's also a [clear duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29775797/283366) in the 2nd comment if you need any more reason

Comment: @Phil The input and option section is confusing. I've linked to the document containing the example code.

Comment: And I've linked to examples for how you can do it with JS. The examples you provided are not code, they're shell commands

Comment: It’d be less confusing after a tutorial—is this a shared account or something? Something doesn’t add up here.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts _"The input and option section is confusing"_... you just need to convert your current body object to a JSON string. Use `options.body = JSON.stringify({ inputs: [...], outputs: [...] })`

Comment: "it's so simple!" - @Phil If it's so simple for you then maybe write the answer. I'm here bc it's not simple for me :)

Comment: I didn't write _"it's so simple"_ anywhere. I don't need to write an answer because there are existing answers. It's also clear from some of your previous questions that you already know how to make requests from Node.js (you used Axios) so I have no idea why this question needed to be asked.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts There are examples of POST requests with headers here (and the web in general). Comments here have provided both reference links and help w/ the syntax errors you’re seeing but didn’t include in the question. 13 years on SO? This still doesn’t add up.

Comment: @DaveNewton I got it working but ran into a few issues. The JSON stringify for the content body (thanks @phil) and it seems the string token variables were not being replaced. I don't know why but I got it working and posted an answer

Answer (score -1):

Here is the curl call converted. The header token variables weren't replaced for some reason so I redefined them directly after.

I've added the responses inline.

```
  async createRenditionOfPSDCall(token, apiKey, inputs, outputs) {
    var url = "https://image.adobe.io/pie/psdService/renditionCreate";

    var options: any = new Object();

    options.headers = {
      "Authorization": `Bearer $token`,
      "x-api-key": `$apiKey`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
    options.headers["x-api-key"] = apiKey;
    options.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";

    // make array
    if (("length" in inputs)==false) {
      inputs = [inputs];
    }

    if (("length" in outputs)==false) {
      outputs = [outputs];
    }

    options.body = JSON.stringify({
      "inputs": inputs,
      "outputs": outputs
    })

    options.method = "post";
    
    var results = await fetch(url, options);
    var text = await results.text();

    if (text.indexOf("{")==0) {
      var links = JSON.parse(text);
      var href = links.self.href;
    }

    var x = {
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "https://image.adobe.io/pie/psdService/status/85cedc52-da8e-4b36-a0bb-8e4fdb4fd7b2"
        }
      }
    }

    return results;
  }
```

Comment: String interpolation with backticks requires curly-braces **and** the dollar sign, e.g., `${foo}`. A JS tutorial or the docs would really be helpful.

Comment: I’d also recommend using [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray#) to check if something is an array instead of relying on a property that could be on anything.

Comment: And using `!(condition)` for checking falsiness.

Comment: @DaveNewton OK. I know that's correct. The curl token format threw me off. I agree on array. In my case I know the data passed in will never have that property but in real applications agreed.

Comment: @DaveNewton my personal preference is I don't like the `(!(condition))` because it's easy to miss the `!`. It's clearer to me to read if `(condition==false)`

Comment: That's fine. Besides being (somewhat, anyway) less-than-canonical JS style there's potential equals v. strict-equals issues now or down the line--just something to be aware of.

Comment: The `length` property check will throw if, say, a string is passed in. It **looks** like you're trying to use it to check for array-ness, but it'll just blow up instead of being useful.

Comment: @DaveNewton well it's an object passed in but thats true but it's an example that is not in production

Comment: @DaveNewton true. the `==` was common but i'm seeing `===` much more often